# CodeIgniter - Use relative path for assets files in header

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on a project in CI and I was trying to use relative  path to access assets (css, js files) . So I've created a constant in config `constants.php` file ... and called this constant instead of `base_url()` to access css files in header. the path it shows

```
http://localhost/project/assets/frontend/plugins/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

Everything is just working fine but when I access a file in different controller, suppose Login controller ... the CSS doesn't load. and after clicking on file,  in page source it shows controller name in path.. which is creating issue. look at the path

```
http://localhost/project/login/assets/frontend/plugins/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

**IN CONSTANTS.PHP**

i've wrote

```
define("ASSETS", "assets/frontend");
```

Can someone here guide where I am doing wrong

Comment: Can you show us the content of `constants.php`?

Comment: Sure..I've edited my questionn.. please check

Comment: How about showing the code that creates the asset link.

Comment: Use an `absolute path`. If you use relative path, it's given it will assume the the base path  from your controller url. You better use `base_url()`, or create a new helper `assets_url(..)` or make `ASSETS` absolute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
define("ASSETS", "/project/assets/frontend");
```

OR

create a helper with function `asset_path()` (I like this method better):

```
function asset_path() {
    return get_instance()->config->base_url() . 'assets/frontend';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to change `ASSETS` constant to

```
define("ASSETS", "/project/assets/frontend");
```

instead of

```
define("ASSETS", "assets/frontend");
```

and access

```
<link href="<?= ASSETS ?>/plugins/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```